# How to Reload the Same layout on View Flipper in Android?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have an Linear Layout inside the View Flipper. When i fling/swipe the layout the same layout reloads the same layout with the animations slide_left_out and slide_right_in. I just have only one layout view. it has the values the image view and text view. When i swipe the view it  just change the next value to that views. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add the swipe/fling functionality? In other words, when the screen is "flung", that's where your code has to come in and "flip" the viewflipper to a different layout.

AFAIK There isn't a built-in way to fling the viewflipper without having to write some code to handle the fling and manually change the viewflipper layout (index).

EDIT:

[Basic Gesture Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

[Flipping Views using `ViewVlipper.setDisplayedChild()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild%28int%29)

Comment: That part of my code is copywritten but I added two links with detailed samples (possibly better than my own code :)